# jQuery Checkbox Not Refreshing On Page Load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

Using jQuery 1.9, I'm writing a WebForm that retrieves data on page load an alters WebFields based on results. One of the fields is a checkbox.

```
<input id="chkFollowUp" type="checkbox" class="form-control"/>
```

I am trying to change the value on page load. The back end says the value has been altered, but the UI remains unchecked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($('#chkFollowUp').prop('checked'));    // return false
        $('#chkFollowUp').prop('checked', true);
        alert($('#chkFollowUp').prop('checked'));    // return true, but UI unchanged
    })
</script>
```

Do I need to refresh the UI to display the new value? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

Solved. In my template the radios and checkboxes are customized using jquery uniform plugin. When you change checkbox/radio state, you will need to sync the customized checkbox/radio using below code:

```
$('#chkFollowUp').prop('checked', true).uniform('refresh');
```

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/otdks6ep/

Comment: Check whether there is any `JS` error in console

Comment: Thank you for your help. Turns out, the template I was using had CheckBoxes and RadioButtons customized using jquery uniform plugin. In that case, I had to use the following code: `$('#chkFollowUp').prop('checked', true).uniform('refresh');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. In my template the radios and checkboxes are customized using jquery uniform plugin. When you change checkbox/radio state, you will need to sync the customized checkbox/radio using below code:

```
$('#chkFollowUp').prop('checked', true).uniform('refresh');
```